# backuppc - will it work with flexraid (or similar)

Tags: raid, software-raid, backup

Will backupcpc work with flexraid?

What I do know is Backuppc must run under linux because of the hard links it uses, which means the file system I believe has to be a certain type other than ntfs/fat.

Are there any other similar software raid solutions it would work with?

I would even consider a different (but similar) backup solution if there were another one that would work with flexraid?

Answer (score 0):

I heard back somewhere else that flexraid does not support hard links, so that means it will not currently work.

I wonder if there are any other similar SAN / raid volume solutions ?